# Add style.css for a specific component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I'm trying to add a CSS file for a specific component in react, but the CSS file apply in all component
How can I add style.css for a specific component?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "gatsby";
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Footer from "../components/Globals/Footer"
import "./crm2.css"


class Crm extends Component {
    render() {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: CSS *is* generally applied globally. Can you include the CSS styles and what you are trying to style in `Crm`? There *are* alternatives to *.css files.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this link on which the narrator is explaining the options you have for styling the React Components. [Styling in React](https://youtu.be/sBws8MSXN7A?t=2049)

Your options are

1. In-Line styling
2. Using variables
3. styling by means of a function or method inside the component

Once you take a look at the video link, you will know what approach suits you the best.

Comment: Down voted as there is no information in the answer that helps the OP. Link is to a youtube video. Can answers please contain information from linked sources in case the linked source is removed or edited.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS `className` must be unique. If you write CSS for this class then it will be applied to the specified component.

There are two components in React

1. Built-in component (like `<p>`, `<div>`, `<span>`, etc)
2. React component (like `<App/>`,`<Product>`, etc)

React components allows you to break up the UI into different pieces so that it can then be reused and handled individually. It is the Dot-notation component like `<UserContext.Provider>` and any component which starts with a capital letter.

These components can be styled if you provide a unique `className` to those components and you write a CSS style for that.

You might have styled the built-in component as shown below

style.css file:

```
p {
font-size:14px;
color: red;
}
```

Using the above approach, the CSS would be applied to all the `<p>` component in all the JSX file.

If you have wanted to style the React component then you need to select those components and styled it as shown below.

```
<Product className = "items" />
```

CSS would be

```
.items {
   color: red;
   ...
}
```